# CSS transforms: rotate vs rotateZ

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I want to know what are the differences between the css transform functions `rotate` and `rotateZ`:

If I applied those properties (with same values) to two different elements I get the same results:

```css
.rotateZ {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotateZ">
  <img src="http://ohdoylerules.com/content/images/css3.svg" />
  <h3>RotateZ</h3>
</div>

<div class="rotate">
  <img src="http://ohdoylerules.com/content/images/css3.svg" />
  <h3>Rotate</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They do the exact same thing. `rotateZ` means 'rotate about the Z axis', and the Z axis points outwards from your screen, basically giving it a third dimension.

You use the same z-axis when you define a property called the `z-index`, which I'm sure you know about.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#funcdef-rotatez

Comment: The exact same thing, with one caveat: Internet Explorer 9 does not support CSS3 3D Transforms, and thus does not support `rotateZ` - just `rotate`. [JSFiddle - open in IE9](https://jsfiddle.net/ksrs8ck0/)